# jquery-chosen Dropdown is not populated when all Gridview items are deleted

Tags: gridview, jquery-chosen

I have a jquery-chosen dropdown box within a Gridview in the FooterTemplate when the user wants to add to the table.
If there are no items in the table, the dropdown properly displays the list that the user can select.  However, if the user deletes all of the items in the table, the dropdown in the EmptyDataTemplate does not display any items.

I believe I have to update the chosen dropdown but is has not worked.

This is my markup:

```
<asp:GridView ID="DelegateInfoGridView" runat="server" 
        AutoGenerateColumns="false" Caption="Delegate Information" 
        CaptionAlign="Top" CssClass="grid" RowStyle-Wrap="true" 
        HorizontalAlign="Left" ShowFooter="true" 
        AllowPaging="true" PageSize="5"  ShowHeaderWhenEmpty="false" onrowediting="DelegateInfoGridView_RowEditing" 
        onrowcancelingedit="DelegateInfoGridView_RowCancelingEdit" onrowdeleting="DelegateInfoGridView_RowDeleting" 
        onrowupdating="DelegateInfoGridView_RowUpdating" 
        ondatabound="DelegateInfoGridView_DataBound" 
        onrowcommand="DelegateInfoGridView_RowCommand">
        <Columns>
             <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Recipient ID">
                <ItemTemplate>
                    <asp:Label ID="deligvLblRecipientID" runat="server" Text='<%# Bind("RecipientID") %>'></asp:Label>
                </ItemTemplate>
             </asp:TemplateField>

             <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Delegate" ItemStyle-Wrap="false"> 
                <ItemTemplate>
                    <asp:Label ID="deligvLblRecipientName" runat="server" Text='<%# Bind("RecipientName") %>'></asp:Label>
                </ItemTemplate>
                <FooterTemplate>
                    <asp:DropDownList ID="deligvDDLRecipientName" runat="server" 
                                        data-placeholder="Choose delegate…" class="chosen-single">
                    </asp:DropDownList>
                </FooterTemplate>
             </asp:TemplateField>
             <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Active"> 
                <ItemTemplate>
                    <asp:Label ID="deligvLblActive" runat="server" Text='<%# (Boolean.Parse(Eval("Active").ToString())) ? "Yes" : "No" %>'></asp:Label>
                </ItemTemplate>         
                 <EditItemTemplate>
                    <asp:DropDownList ID="deligvDDLActive" runat="server" Text='<%# (Boolean.Parse(Eval("Active").ToString())) ? "Yes" : "No" %>'>
                        <asp:ListItem>Yes</asp:ListItem>
                        <asp:ListItem>No</asp:ListItem>
                    </asp:DropDownList>
                </EditItemTemplate> 
                <FooterTemplate>
                    <asp:DropDownList ID="deligvDDLActiveInsert" runat="server">
                        <asp:ListItem Selected="True">Yes</asp:ListItem>
                        <asp:ListItem>No</asp:ListItem>
                    </asp:DropDownList>
                </FooterTemplate>                         
            </asp:TemplateField>
            <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Action" ItemStyle-Wrap="false" ItemStyle-HorizontalAlign="Center">
                 <ItemTemplate>
                    <asp:Button ID="deligvEditButton" runat="server" CausesValidation="False" CommandName="Edit" 
                                Text="Edit" CssClass="gridActionbutton">
                    </asp:Button>
                    &nbsp;<asp:Button ID="deligvDeleteButton" runat="server" CausesValidation="False" CommandName="Delete" 
                                Text="Delete" CssClass="gridActionbutton"  OnClientClick="return confirm('Are you sure you want to delete this Delegate Information?')" >
                    </asp:Button>
                </ItemTemplate>
                <EditItemTemplate>
                    <asp:Button ID="deligvUpdateButton" runat="server" CausesValidation="False" CommandName="Update" 
                                    Text="Update" CssClass="gridActionbutton"></asp:Button>
                    &nbsp;<asp:Button ID="deligvCancelButton" runat="server" CausesValidation="False" CommandName="Cancel" 
                                    Text="Cancel" CssClass="gridActionbutton"></asp:Button>
                </EditItemTemplate>
                <FooterTemplate>
                    <asp:Button ID="deligvAddButton" runat="server" CommandName="Add" Text="Add Delegate" Width="90%" CausesValidation="false" 
                                CssClass="gridActionbutton">
                    </asp:Button>
                </FooterTemplate>
            </asp:TemplateField>
        </Columns>
        <EmptyDataTemplate>
            <tr>
                <th>Recipient ID</th>
                <th>Delegate</th>
                <th>Active</th>
                <th>Action</th>
            </tr>
            <tr> 
                <td colspan="4" style="text-align:center;">
                    No Delegates were found for you. Delegates can be added by clicking the 'Add Delegate' Button.
                </td> 
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td></td>
                <td>
                    <asp:DropDownList ID="deligvDDLRecipientName" runat="server" 
                                        data-placeholder="Choose delegate…" class="chosen-single">
                    </asp:DropDownList>
                </td>
                <td>
                     <asp:DropDownList ID="deligvDDLActiveInsert" runat="server">
                        <asp:ListItem Selected="True">Yes</asp:ListItem>
                        <asp:ListItem>No</asp:ListItem>
                    </asp:DropDownList>
                </td>
                <td>
                    <asp:Button ID="deligvAddButton" runat="server" CommandName="Add" Text="Add Delegate" Width="90%" CausesValidation="false" 
                        CssClass="gridActionbutton">
                    </asp:Button>
                </td>
            </tr>
        </EmptyDataTemplate>
     </asp:GridView>
```

This is the code-behind that populates the dropdown in the Footer:

```
 protected void DelegateInfoGridView_DataBound(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        try
        {
            m_strUserID = CommonMethods.ParseUserID(User.Identity.Name);

            //Get the Footer controls that have the new entry data
            Control tFooterControls = getFooterControls(DelegateInfoGridView);
            DropDownList ddlRecipientNames = tFooterControls.FindControl("deligvDDLRecipientName") as DropDownList;
            m_strXmlTableData = m_pagingClient.GetAllPossibleDelegates(m_strUserID);
            DataTable tdtAllDelegates = CommonMethods.ParseXML(m_strXmlTableData);
            ddlRecipientNames.DataSource = tdtAllDelegates;
            ddlRecipientNames.DataTextField = "RecipientName";
            ddlRecipientNames.DataValueField = "RecipientID";
            ddlRecipientNames.DataBind();
            ddlRecipientNames.Items.Insert(0, new ListItem("", "0"));//This is needed for the jquery-chosen dropdown to add data-holder text
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            //TO DO: Response.Redirect("~/Error.aspx");
        }
    }
```

This is my javascript:

```
 <script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function () {
        //Configure the DropDownBox using the 'chosen' jquery plugin
        $(".chosen-single").chosen({
            search_contains: true,
            no_results_text: "Sorry, no match!"                           
        });
    });

    $('#deligvAddButtonEmpty').click(function () {
        $(".chosen-single").chosen().val('').trigger("chosen:updated");
    });

</script>
```

So when the button, deligvAddButtonEmpty, is clicked the items are not added to the dropdown.  I stepped thru the code and the method, DelegateInfoGridView_DataBound, is called at the data is returned.  But the dropdown is empty.

I believe my javascript is not correct but I don't know how to fix it.
Any suggestions would be appreciated.

Thanks.

**UPDATE**

I changed the javascript on the button click to this:

```
 $('#deligvAddButtonEmpty').click(function () {
        $("#deligvDDLRecipientName").trigger("chosen:updated");
    });
```

But still the dropdown is empty when the grid is empty.

**UPDATE**

I am trying to debug the javascript using Firebug and it seems that the .click function is not called. At least, when I put a breakpoint within the function it does not stop as it does in the document.ready function.
I am using MasterPages and I have the attribute, ClientIDMode = 'Static' but I might not have the 'selector' defined correctly.

**UPDATE**

It is not when the 'Add Button' is clicked but when the 'Delete button' is clicked and there are no more items in the grid that the chosen dropdown list is not refreshed.
However, I cannot seem to get the click event to trigger for the button.  This is my jquery click function:

```
 $(document).on("click", "input[id$=deligvDeleteButton]", function () {
        alert("Delegate delete button clicked");
    });
```

**UPDATE**
At least, now the click function is being triggered...
I added ClientIDMode-'Static' to the controls that I am accessing and I put the 'click' function within the document.ready() function. However, the update is not adding the list to the dropdown.  This is the function:

```
$("input[id$=deligvDeleteButton]").click(function () {
              $("input[id$=deligvDDLRecipientName]").val('').trigger("chosen:updated");
            });
```

**UPDATE**

I don't know if this is the problem but it might have to do with the control IDs in the jquery script when in the GridView or in the EmptyDataTemplate.  I keep the IDs the same for the dropdown list in the GridView or in the EmptyDataTemplate.  In the code-behind, I identify which control is used by determining if the FooterControl is null.  Then the rest of the C# code is the same because the IDs are the same. However, in the javascript, this may be a problem if the ids are the same.

How can you identify the control in the EmptyDataTemplate and not the Gridview?

**UPDATE**

I don't know if this is the problem but it might have to do with the control IDs in the jquery script when in the GridView or in the EmptyDataTemplate.  I keep the IDs the same for the dropdown list in the GridView or in the EmptyDataTemplate.  In the code-behind, I identify which control is used by determining if the FooterControl is null.  Then the rest of the C# code is the same because the IDs are the same. However, in the javascript, this may be a problem if the ids are the same.

How can you identify the control in the EmptyDataTemplate and not the Gridview?

I used the following javascript to get the IDs of the 2 dropdown controls and update both of them and the dropdown list is still not populated:

```
 $("input[id$=deligvDeleteButton]").click(function () {               
            $("[id*='deligvDDLRecipientName']").each(function () {
                alert($(this).attr('id'));
                $(this).val("").trigger("chosen:updated");
            });            
        });
```

The alert displays the ID. One is 'deligvDDLRecipientName' and the other is deligvDDLRecipientName_chosen.  I update both of them with the .trigger function but the list is still not populated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figured this out...
In case anybody has this problem...

It had nothing to do with the chosen plugin.
It was the way I identified if the FooterControl was instantiated.  I checked for null.  But when a user deletes all of the rows, the FooterControl is not null but you still need to use the EmptyTemplateData control.
So instead of checking for null, I checked for Row Count > 0.
That worked.